# FCM notification messages help to keep app services alive, but FCM data messages don't

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service, cordova-plugin-fcm

I've been trying to keep my app foreground services alive on Oreo by looking into my app services since i'm implementing FCM data messages, but i've found out that app gets inactive , it doesn't happens when i'm sending FCM notification messages.

This is the code i'm using to catch  data messages:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    // Cordova Callback
    FCMPlugin.sendPushPayload(data);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this , FCMPluginActivity.class);
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0 , resultIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mBuilder = new Builder(this, "0");
    }else{
        mBuilder = new Builder(this);
    }

    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(getApplicationInfo().icon)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("0", "Playback status", importance);
        notificationChannel.setShowBadge(false);

        assert mNotificationManager != null;
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    assert mNotificationManager != null;
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

What can i do to keep my app foreground services alive on Oreo by using FCM data messages?

Answer (score 0):

After watching [Google news about battery usage restrictions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pumf_4yjTMc) i've succesfully fixed it by mixing my code with a Foreground Service, it seems that FCM data messages weren't enough to keep my app alive.